# Why is Ali's father crying at the mosque?

Tags: plot-explanation, children-of-heaven

In the Iranian film [Children of Heaven / Bačče-hâ-ye âsemân / بچه‌های آسمان](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Heaven), at around 46:20, why is Ali's father crying while preparing tea at the mosque?

Possible reasons could be...

1. Because of his poverty.
2. Some religious significance (sermons are audible in the mosque, but not given in the subtitles).

But want to know the definite reason(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a religious ceremony in iran named ashoura which the people cry on the death of muhammad's grandson named  hussain. in the movie the flags and other things around is the symbols of this ceremony.
same as that took place in iraq or lebenan and ...